# restkit project integration error using cocoapods

Tags: ios5, restkit, cocoapods

I am using Restkit for webservice client in ios application..i used cocoapods to install the restkit in my sample project. But it is giving semantic issue, and parsing errors when i am building.

I used this link to install Restkit using cocoapods

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-restkit-v0.20.x-via-cocoapods

errors are like this

```
/RKHTTPUtilities.m:69:40: error: unexpected '@' in program
        statusCodesToNamesDictionary = @{



/ObjectMapping/RKHTTPUtilities.m: error: unexpected '@' in program
    return [RKStatusCodesToNamesDictionary() objectForKey:@(statusCode)];
                                                          ^
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're compiling with an older version of Xcode that doesn't support [object literals](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/398-objective-c-literals-part-1/). You can fix this by either updating Xcode, or using an older version of restkit in your podfile like `pod "restkit", "~>0.10.3"`.

Comment: An optional but probably quite difficult way to get around doing either of these is to run your own version of Apple's LLVM compiler with whatever version of Xcode you have running.

Comment: thank you @orta ..i was having trouble for the past 2 days..can u tell me the other way to work with this xcode..and that object literals link is also really helpful..thank you again